# Android HorizontalScrollView inside ListView scrollTo

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView as an item of the ListView, so as I call getView() of the adapter, I call within it HSV.scrollTo(pos, 0) but the HSV is always from position (0,0)

I'm guessing this is because the row view is not fully generated, but if so how can I make it work ?

thank you

code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.watchlist_list_item2, null);

ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
scroll.scrollTo(320, 0);
...
...
...
return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a delay of 20ms before the scrolling action

Answer (score 0):

Inside activity where adapter is being added to listview  you can do this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 200);
```

I think you have done this if not, try it.